# javafx - init tabs (of tab pane) on startup

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using eclipse & scene builder.

I has defined the main window as follow:

[image]

I want to define the "Outgoing Messages" tab with X (X is calculated on run time) of elements (the elements defined at different fxml file).

When I'm creating the main window:

```
private Stage primaryStage;   
private AnchorPane rootLayout;

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("ABC");

    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("MainLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How can I update the "Outgoing Messages" tabs as I described above ?

Thanks

Comment: Does the `Outgoing Messages` tab has its own `FXML` ?

Comment: My purpose is to create the outgoing message tab from X same elements (each element has it's own fxml file)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`<fx:include>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements) inside your FXML for `Outgoing Messages`. This will automatically load X number of fxml before loading the main FXML. After all the incude FXML's are loaded, the FXML for `Outgoing Messages` is prepared and shown.

**Update**

If you have dynamic increase/decrease in elemtents, use the `initialize()` of the `Outgoing Messages` to populate the elements inside it instead of using `<fx:incude>`.

Lets consider (*you may have your own logic*) your `Outgoing Messages` has a `VBox` which is to be filled with dynamic no of elements(*BorderPane in this case*) which is inside `X.fxml` (*You may have different FXML or you can create you own control at runtime and add it*) :

```
pubic class OutgoingMessagesController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private VBox vbox;

    public void initialize(java.net.URL location, java.util.ResourceBundle resources) {

        //Whatever your logic is, I am considering a dynamic number here

        for(int i=0; i<dynamicNumber; i++){
            BorderPane borderPane = FXMLoader.load(getClass().getResource("X.fxml"));
            vbox.getChildren.add(borderPane);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use <fx:include> beacuse I know X at run time (X can be 3 at the begging, and change to 9 and ...

Comment: I have updated the answer, let me know if you are looking for something else

Comment: Thanks, it help. But how can I create different controller for different tab ? (Is the right way is to use fx:include and chose the controller via scene builder, or there is a better way (better logic solution) ?

Comment: defining the controlller in the fxml is the standard way. You can also set the controller through the loader using `loader.setController()`.